# Getting edittext values from recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to get values from the list of edit text from the Recycler view.

[image]
This is the layout

This is the code I am using in Activity class to get values from recycler view.
Code consists of Error message in comments

```
private void getPriceQuantity() {
        List<PriceQuantity> priceQuantitiesToAdd = new ArrayList<PriceQuantity>();
        for(int i=0;i<priceQuantities.size();i++)
        {
            View view=priceQuantityRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);
            if(view!=null)
            {

//  this is the error i am receiving
//  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable 
//  android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

                EditText price = view.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
                Log.d(TAG," price is "+price.getText().toString());
                EditText quantity = view.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my view holder in Adapter class:

```
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            productPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
            productQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_quantity);
            deletePriceQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deletePriceQuantityButton);
            linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceQuantity);

            deletePriceQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(priceQuantities.size() >1){
                        priceQuantities.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

This is onBindView Holder from Adapter class

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        addImageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(priceQuantities.size() <=2 ){
                Log.d("clicked","Add image is clicked");
                priceQuantities.add(new PriceQuantity());
                Log.d("clicked","size of array list "+priceQuantities.size());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The issue is solved. This link was helpful. https://www.creospiders.com/2016/04/how-to-access-each-view-of-item-by.html

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this code :

```
        Log.d(TAG," price is "+price.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder) priceQuantityRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
if (null != holder) {
   EditText price = (EditText) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
}
```

Comment: I have a link with this issue it says to call these method from onTouchListener or onClickListener or onScrollListener. I have called the getPriceQuantity from the onClickListener still this does not solve the issue. https://www.creospiders.com/2016/04/how-to-access-each-view-of-item-by.html